# HC12 transmission sensing

Tags: c, arduino

I am new to arduino and I am using an accelerometer to measure acceleration on a moving rocket. I am using the HC12 wireless transmitter to do this.

What I am trying to do is to begin sending data to the computer via the HC12 transmitter only when a certain change in z axis acceleration is sensed.

I am confused unto what to do with the functions that I have made to pass values of x, y, z and data into the function Hc12.

This Hc12 function is only meant to run once every 30 seconds whereas the loop function should run about 3 times per second.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is the following:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial HC12(7,6);

//initialising variables and functions
const int numReadings = 15;
int readings[numReadings];
int index = 0;
float total = 0;
int inputPin = A1;

float test;

const int numReadings1 = 15;
int readings1[numReadings1];
int index1 = 0;
float total1 = 0;
int inputPin1 = A2;

const int numReadings2 = 15;
int readings2[numReadings2];
int index2 = 0;
float total2 = 0;
int inputPin2 = A3;

float x;
float y;
float z;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(115200);

 if ((readings2[index2]-readings2[index2-1])>0.5){
  HC12.begin(115200);
 }
 
 for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++)
 readings[thisReading] = 0;

}

float Hc12(float x, float y, float z, float data)
{
  float test;
  readings2[index2] =analogRead(inputPin2);
test =readings2[index2]-readings2[index2-1];

if ((test)>0.1){

      HC12.println(data); 
}//send data
return test;
 delay(30000);
}
 
void loop() {

//x moving avg
  total = total-readings[index];
  readings[index] =analogRead(inputPin);
  total = total +readings[index];
  index = index + 1;

  if (index>=numReadings)
  index = 0;

  x = total/numReadings;

  //y moving avg
  
  total1 = total1-readings1[index1];
  readings1[index1] =analogRead(inputPin1);
  total1 = total1 +readings1[index1];
  index1 = index1 + 1;

  if (index1>=numReadings1)
  index1 = 0;

  y = total1/numReadings1;

  //z moving avg
  
  total2 = total2-readings2[index2];
  readings2[index2] =analogRead(inputPin2);
  total2 = total2 +readings2[index2];
  index2 = index2 + 1;

  if (index2>=numReadings2)
  index2 = 0;

  z = total2/numReadings2;

   //z moving avg
  
  total2 = total2-readings2[index2];
  readings2[index2] =analogRead(inputPin2);
  total2 = total2 +readings2[index2];
  index2 = index2 + 1;

  if (index2>=numReadings2)
  index2 = 0;

  z = total2/numReadings2;


String data = "";
data = data + x + "," + y + "," + z ;
 
  
 delay(30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function below. or Am I missing some points?

```
float Hc12(float x, float y, float z, float data)
```

I didn't check the remaining code whether there is any other mistake or not by the way.